# Is there a good way to make a button in Android do different things depending on if you click on the left half or right half of the button?

Tags: android-layout, custom-controls

In an android app I am making, I would like to make a button that does different things depending on whether the user presses the left half of the button or the right half of the button. Right now I'm trying to figure out what would be the best way to accomplish this.

Some other specific requirements:
1. I'm planning on using the button 1 to 4 times per Activity.
2. It would be very helpful if I could be able to rotate the button (e.g. 90 degrees, 180 degrees so it's upside-down)

One idea I have had is putting two buttons side by side and putting a text-view on the top to make it look like one button. I found this doesn't really work well. It requires lots of effort to get it to show up properly and gets messed up when even small changes are made.

Another idea I had was making a custom button by extending the view class. Problem is I have no experience doing something like that and most of the tutorials I've seen use it to make paint programs.

What would be the best way to create something like this??

Edit: When I say rotate the button, I don't mean that the button needs to rotate when clicked or when some other action is performed. Just that it is facing in the direction I need it to be when the app loads. Also it only needs to be facing in the standard 4 directions (i.e. Down, Up, Left, Right). Sorry I wasn't more clear on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i created the first approach using framelayout as follow:

```
  <FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:onClick="rotate">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/view"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView2">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Button text"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display1"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
</FrameLayout>
```

for rotating any view create your anim.xml file inside `anim` folder in `res` 
`right click` on `res` -> `new android res dir`-> choose `anim` then create anim file right click on `anim` folder you just created and `new anim res file`  and the past the code in side it , this will rotate your framelayout in this certain code by 180 degeree

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:fillAfter="true">

<rotate
    android:duration="500"
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:toDegrees="180" />
</set>
```

use it as follow on kotlin

```
 fun rotate(view: View) {

    val rotate = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(
            applicationContext,
            R.anim.rotate
    )

    frame.startAnimation(rotate)

}
```

Comment: I was a little unclear on what I meant by "Rotate". I have edited and clarified my question. Sorry for making you go though that extra work. Also, I using your solution, I discovered that I can rotate it by using `android:rotation=` in FrameLayout so you don't need to edit your answer for me.

Comment: I feel happy that this answer helped you, please upvote and accept the answer